# C++ inline Assembler help. (error c2400)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I wrote a program that does a simple Binary Search algorithm. I'm trying to convert it into assemble code. I used the Disassembler to get the assembly code. I'm trying to paste it into _asm. I've tried so many ways and it's just not working.

I tried

```
_asm(" . . . .");
_asm(  );
_asm{ }    <--- -Currently going with this way for c++. seems to work well.
```

seen somewhere online people saying put '\' at the end of each line. That hasn't worked for me.

Here's the code. I'll comment where the errors are. well, I have 13 as of now. Some I won't list because they're the same as other errors. Once I fix one or 2 I should be able to fix them all. The orignal c++ code for the function is also in there.It's commented out.

```
bool binarySearch(int searchNum,int myArray[],int size){

        _asm{ 
     push        ebp  
     mov         ebp,esp  
     sub         esp,0F0h  
     push        ebx  
     push        esi  
     push        edi  
     lea         edi,[ebp-0F0h]  
     mov         ecx,3Ch 
     mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
     rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
      // 217:   int first=0,last=size-1,middle;
     mov         dword ptr [first],0  
     mov         eax,dword ptr [size]       // ERROR! Error 2   error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found ']'
     sub         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [last],eax  
      // 218:   bool found = false;
     mov         byte ptr [found],0  

     //  220:   while (first <= last)
     mov         eax,dword ptr [first]
     cmp         eax,dword ptr [last] 
     jg          binarySearch+80h (0B51970h)        //ERROR! Error  4   error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found '('   


      // 222:       middle = (first + last)/2;
     mov         eax,dword ptr [first] ;        //  Error   5   error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('   

     add         eax,dword ptr [last] ;
     cdq  
     sub         eax,edx  
     sar         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [middle],eax  

     //  224:       if(searchNum > myArray[middle])
     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     mov         ecx,dword ptr [myArray]  
     mov         edx,dword ptr [searchNum]  
     cmp         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax*4]  
     jle         binarySearch+61h (0B51951h)  // Error  8   error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('   

     //  226:           first = middle +1;
     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     add         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [first],eax  
     jmp         binarySearch+7Eh (0B5196Eh)  

      // 228:       else if (searchNum < myArray[middle])
     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     mov         ecx,dword ptr [myArray]  
     mov         edx,dword ptr [searchNum]  
     cmp         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax*4]  
     jge         binarySearch+7Ah (0B5196Ah)  

      // 230:           last = middle -1;
     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     sub         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [last],eax  

      // 232:       else 
     jmp         binarySearch+7Eh (0B5196Eh)    // Error    18  error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found '('

      // 233:           return true;
     mov         al,1           // Error    19  error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('   

     jmp         binarySearch+82h (0B51972h)  

     jmp         binarySearch+32h (0B51922h)    // Error    22  error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('   

      // 236:   return false;
     xor         al,al  

     pop         edi  
     pop         esi  
     pop         ebx  
     mov         esp,ebp  
     pop         ebp  
     ret  

        };

        /*
        int first=0,last=size-1,middle;
        bool found = false;

        while (first <= last)
        {
            middle = (first + last)/2;

            if(searchNum > myArray[middle])
            {
                first = middle +1;
            }
            else if (searchNum < myArray[middle])
            {
                last = middle -1;
            }
            else 
                return true;
        }

        return false;

        */
    }
```

Comment: You can't just copy generated assembly and paste into inline asm blocks. First of all - it is very likely that all addresses are not usable in your code.

Comment: If you are writing a whole function anyway, then I would recommend using masm and a separate source file. You don't even need to fiddle with custom settings, because in VS 2008+ you can create an empty file.asm and then import it into your project using "add existing item" and the build rules will be created automatically. The inline assembler is also a bit buggy (unless they improved it).

Comment: For something this big, I recommend writing a separate assembly unit; don't inline with C or C++.

Comment: BTW: You don't need the disassembler for this, you can let the compiler create an assembler sourcefile as well, which would resolve some problems you haven't noticed yet (like invalid stack offsets) with your current approach.

Comment: I posted an inlined and a standalone version for you, so you can see the differences. The inline assmebler handles access to variables, so you don't need the `dword ptr[]` part when accessing the variables. In assembly it's also not strictly neccessary, but it doesn't lead to errors either.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments and help. Very new to assembly as you can see. going to try the different approach with inline as @Devolus said then I may take a look at putting the code in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the (almost 1:1) working code you posted for a standalone assembly.

binsearch.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
    bool BinSearch(int searchNum, int myArray[], int arraySize);
};

// This is the inlined version.
bool BinSearchInline(int searchNum, int myArray[], int arraySize)
{
    int middle;
    int first;
    int last;
    char found;

    _asm
    {
     push        ebx  
     push        esi  
     push        edi  

     mov         first,0  
     mov         eax, arraySize
     sub         eax,1  
     mov         last ,eax  
     mov         found,0

LocalLoop:

     mov         eax, first
     cmp         eax, last
     jg          NotFound

     mov         eax, first

     add         eax, last
     cdq  
     sub         eax,edx  
     sar         eax,1  
     mov         middle,eax  

     mov         eax,middle
     mov         ecx,myArray
     mov         edx,searchNum
     cmp         edx, dword ptr [ecx+eax*4]  
     jle         MaybeLower

     mov         eax, middle
     add         eax,1  
     mov         first, eax  
     jmp         WhileLoop

MaybeLower:
     mov         eax, middle
     mov         ecx, myArray
     mov         edx, searchNum
     cmp         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax*4]  
     jge         Found

     mov         eax, middle
     sub         eax,1  
     mov         last, eax  

     jmp         WhileLoop

Found:
     mov         al,1
     jmp         Done

WhileLoop:
     jmp         LocalLoop

NotFound:
     xor         al,al  

Done:
     pop         edi  
     pop         esi  
     pop         ebx  
    };
}

int main(int argc, char*arg[])
{
    int testvalues[7];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        testvalues[i] = i;

    bool b = BinSearch(8, testvalues, 7);       // false, value not in array
    b = BinSearch(3, testvalues, 7);        // true, value is in array.

    b = BinSearchInline(8, testvalues, 7);      // false
    b = BinSearchInline(3, testvalues, 7);      // true

    return 0;
}
```

binsearch.asm

```
.486
.model flat, C
option casemap :none

.code

BinSearch PROC, searchNum:DWORD, myArray:PTR DWORD, arraySize:DWORD

    LOCAL first:DWORD
    LOCAL middle:DWORD
    LOCAL last:DWORD
    LOCAL found:BYTE

     push        ebx  
     push        esi  
     push        edi  

    ; This block is only for debugging stack errors and should be removed.
    ; lea         edi,[ebp-0F0h]  
    ; mov         ecx,3Ch 
    ; mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
    ; rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 

     mov         dword ptr [first],0  
     mov         eax,dword ptr [arraySize]
     sub         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [last],eax  
     mov         byte ptr [found],0     ; not even used.

@@Loop:
     mov         eax,dword ptr [first]
     cmp         eax,dword ptr [last] 
     jg          @@NotFound

     mov         eax,dword ptr [first]

     add         eax,dword ptr [last]
     cdq  
     sub         eax,edx  
     sar         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [middle],eax  

     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     mov         ecx,dword ptr [myArray]  
     mov         edx,dword ptr [searchNum]  
     cmp         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax*4]  
     jle         @@MaybeLower

     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     add         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [first],eax  
     jmp         @@WhileLoop

@@MaybeLower:
     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     mov         ecx,dword ptr [myArray]  
     mov         edx,dword ptr [searchNum]  
     cmp         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax*4]  
     jge         @@Found

     mov         eax,dword ptr [middle]  
     sub         eax,1  
     mov         dword ptr [last],eax  

     jmp         @@WhileLoop

@@Found:
     mov         al,1
     jmp         @@Done

@@WhileLoop:
     jmp         @@Loop

@@NotFound:
     xor         al,al  

@@Done:
     pop         edi  
     pop         esi  
     pop         ebx  

     ret  

BinSearch ENDP

END
```